# Install Android Studio in Linux Mint 17 without PPA

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I am still a fairly new user to the world of Linux. At the moment, I am wanting to install [Android Stuido](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) onto my pc which runs Linux Mint 17.

I found this [article](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1953) which has an explanation about how to install the software. When I get to point 3 ***"Extract the compressed file, you can now see "android-studio"  directory, copy "android-studio" to any location where you want to install it."***, I get a bit fuzzy with what to do. When is say ***"copy "android-studio" to any location where you want to install it."***, I read this as saying - it doesn't matter where you copy it, but my rational thinking is saying - "everything has a place so put it with the other programs!!" I guess my question is, does it matter where you install the software from?

Answer (score 0):

Put it somewhere to be reached easily (although you can add shortcut to your system) like home folder.

you can put it in other places but it may cause troubles about the permission thing.